# View files without lines with certain string

Tags: command-line, less

Searching for a program like `tail` or `less` which let me view my logs without lines that contain a certain string. For example view my syslog without UFW (`[UFW BLOCK]`) entry lines.

Comment: While it's not easy to provide a solution to your exact problem description with this feature, you might be interested to know that `less` offers the possibility to filter the displayed lines after a regex pattern. You can use this feature by typing `&` followed by the pattern, and you can revert it by typing `&` alone.

Comment: Telling ufw to use it's own logfile, instead of syslog, is another option. Or have syslog (rsyslog, etc) filter ufw messages into their own file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pattern match inversion option `-v` for `grep` is really helpful for this:

```
grep -v 'UFW BLOCK' /var/log/syslog
```

This will show you all lines not containing `UFW BLOCK`. As `grep` uses basic regular expressions by default, the inclusion of the brackets will make it search for any of the individual characters of 'UFW BLOCK' including the space. You'll probably end up with no output. If you need to ensure that there are brackets around the string, either escape them `\[UFW BLOCK\]`, or use the `-F` option of `grep` to only include fixed strings (Thanks to [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) and [Steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for the advice on this):

```
grep -Fv '[UFW BLOCK]' /var/log/syslog
```

You can make it easier to view by piping the output to a pager like `less`:

```
grep -v 'UFW BLOCK' /var/log/syslog | less
```

Or redirect the output to a file in your home directory for later viewing:

```
grep -v 'UFW BLOCK' /var/log/syslog > ~/filtered_syslog
```

Comment: You can also use the `fgrep` command which is equivalent to `grep -F` .

Comment: @TulainsCórdova grep's man says that "Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is  deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified". I don't know if they will ever act on this deprecation, but I guess using these commands isn't best practice

Answer (score 12):

With `less` command's `&` option it's possible to filter out to display only desired matched pattern as below,

```
& /PATTERN/
```

in your case if you want filter lines with `UFW BLOCK` to don't display in output, you could simply use `&!` as below:

```
&! /UFW BLOCK/
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `sed`'s `d` command to delete the lines with the pattern from the stream:

```
sed '/\[UFW BLOCK\]/d' /var/log/syslog
```

We escape `[]` as normally they denote a character class, meaning "match anything inside here"

Answer (score 5):

You can use any tool with editing capabilities. You've already been given solutions using `grep` and `sed`, here are a few other choices. All of these can easily be piped to `less` or `more` or anything else.

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -ne 'print unless /\[UFW BLOCK\]/' /var/log/syslog
   ```

   Since this is Perl, [TIMTOWDI!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

   ```
   perl -pe '$_="" if /\[UFW BLOCK\]/' /var/log/syslog
   perl -ne '/\[UFW BLOCK\]/ || print' /var/log/syslog
   perl -ne 'print if !/\[UFW BLOCK\]/' /var/log/syslog
   perl -ne '!/\[UFW BLOCK\]/ && print' /var/log/syslog
   perl -ne '/\[UFW BLOCK\]/ ? "" : print' /var/log/syslog
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   awk '!/\[UFW BLOCK\]/' file
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` too:

```
awk '!/PATTERN/' log
```

I use it when I've got more than of one "pattern" and I don't want to use two `grep` like:

```
... | grep -v foo | grep -v bar
```

which the syntax is:

```
awk '!/PATTERN/ && !/PATTERN2/' log
```

Comment: "I use it when I've got more than of one "pattern" and I don't want to use two grep like"------ `grep -Ev "foo|bar"`?

Comment: You can also use `-e` to define multiple patterns. `grep -v -e 'foo' -e 'bar'`

Comment: @AFSHIN (Don't know how my comment get removed), I meant for a logical and not or ;)